# How to initialize flexslider on http.get callback data in angular 2

Tags: angular, callback, flexslider, http-get

I need to fetch 2 json files data one after another. That means I am calling one json file, depending on data received calling another json file. This I have done. Concern is I need to initialize a flexsider on data received from second json file. Can someone help me.

```js
export class popularProductsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public popProductIds: string[] = [];
  public popProductData: Array < Object > ;
  private sub: any;
  public errorMessage: string;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private popService: PopularDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ popular-products.component ngOnInit");
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      this.popService.getPopularProdData(id).then(
        //console.log("inCallbackroute")
        popData => this.extractPopularProducts(popData)
      );
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // landing Most Popular for large devices
    $('.js-landing-upper-carousel').flexslider({
      selector: '.slides:first > li',
      animation: 'slide',
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshowSpeed: 3000,
      animationSpeed: 500,
      slideshow: false,
      controlNav: false,
      reverse: false,
      itemWidth: 358,
      itemMargin: 12,
      minItems: 1,
      maxItems: 3,
      move: 1,
      smoothHeight: false,
      useCSS: false,
      customDirectionNav: $('.promotions-carousel-navigation a')
    });
  }

  extractPopularProducts(popData) {
      for (var i = 0; i < popData.MarketingSpotData[0].baseMarketingSpotActivityData.length; i++) {
        this.popProductIds.push(popData.MarketingSpotData[0].baseMarketingSpotActivityData[i].productId);
      }
      this.popService.getPopularProductDetails(this.popProductIds).then(
        popData1 => this.popProductData = popData1,
        error => this.errorMessage = < any > error
      );
    }
}
```

```js
@
Injectable()
export class PopularDataService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  private popularProdUrl = '/assets/json-mocks/popular-prod.json';
  private popularProdDetailsUrl = '/assets/json-mocks/popular-prod-details.json';
  getPopularProdData(id: number): Promise < Array < Object >> {
    // return;
    console.log("popular-data.service.ts || getPopularProdData. id = " + id + " url = " + this.popularProdUrl);
    return this.http.get(this.popularProdUrl).toPromise().then(response => response.json());
  }
  getPopularProductDetails(popProductIds: string[]): Promise < Array < Object >> {
    console.log("popular-data.service.ts || getPopularProductDetails. popProductIds = " + popProductIds + " url = " + this.popularProdDetailsUrl);
    return this.http.get(this.popularProdDetailsUrl).toPromise().then(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

I am not sure where to put my code to initialize my flexslider. ngAfterViewInit getting called prior to my data. Hence it is not working. Please can someone advise me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put it right after you get your data!

```
  this.popService.getPopularProdData(id).then(

    popData => this.extractPopularProducts(popData)
```

HERE

```
  );
```